# CRC test vectors for CRC16 (CCITT)

Tags: crc

Does anyone know of some CRC test vectors for [CRC16-CCITT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Commonly_used_and_standardized_CRCs)?

I do not have a CRC implementation I can trust and either need to test someone's implementation or my own. (For CRC32, I use the [PNG code](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-CRCAppendix.html) as the gold standard, as it's a reputable reference implementation.)

([this site's CRC calculator](http://zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html) looks useful but I need to verify correctness somehow)

---

UPDATE: The above CRC calculator looks useful <s>but it takes only ascii, no way to enter hex.</s> --- it's very awkward to enter hex input, though. (ASCII `12` in hex can be entered as `%31%32`, so you can't just copy+paste a long string of hexadecimal bytes; also the `%` character doesn't seem to have an escape)

I have verified [this online calculator](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html), which takes hex inputs, against the Boost test vectors for CRC16, CRC16-CCITT, and CRC32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost has a nice CRC implementation you can test against. As far as I know it's possible to configure it for CRC16.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/crc/index.html

There seems to be an example of how to set it up to simulate CCITT on this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/crc/crc.html

Comment: +1 and accepted: not for the reason you mentioned but because their test code has a test vector: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/crc/test/crc_test.cpp (see std_data and  std_crc_ccitt_result)

Comment: Great, even a blind hen sometimes finds a grain of corn :) Seriously, boost libraries tends to surprise positively.

Comment: implementation may be nice, and correct, but like most abstract template libraries it is pretty opaque to look at. :-(

Comment: How do I know that the Boost implementation is correct?   Does the original CCITT spec contain any test vectors?

Comment: "Does the original CCITT spec contain any test vectors?" -- oh, this is a pet peeve of mine. https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/669.php

Answer (score 2):

Python's `binascii` package has had CRC-16 for a while.

Use `binascii.crc_hqx(val, 0xFFFF)` - the previous example are...

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import binascii
>>> tv = binascii.a2b_hex("12345670")
>>> hex(binascii.crc_hqx(tv, 0xFFFF))
'0xb1e4'
>>> tv = "123456789".encode("ascii")
>>> hex(binascii.crc_hqx(tv, 0xFFFF))
'0x29b1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two test vectors for `CCITT-16 CRC` (whose polynomial is `X16 + X12 + X5 + 1` (0x1021 in big-endian hex representation); initial CRC value is `0xFFFF`. XOR value out is zero.) are:

```
0x12345670 = 0xB1E4

0x5A261977 = 0x1AAD
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this one:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC16CCITT.java.html

```
"123456789".getBytes("ASCII"); -> 0x29b1
```